# How to position two elements centered on top of each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem:
I have a form with a button underneath it to submit (post) from data with jQuery ajax(). I want for the button to be replaced with a spinner (animated png) for the duration of server ajax call. But such a trivial task is impossible in css to do right.

What i have tried:
I have placed button and image inside a bootstrap row. Ox ajax call I have set button display to none and img display to block. But because this two are not of the same size makes the whole page flicker, breaks the positioning of other elements and so on.

Another idea was to try to place both elements on top of each other with absolute positioning. But, stupid as css is I cannot center it on the middle of the row.

Is there a way to position both elements on top of each other so I can control their visibility?
Please bear in mind that I cannot used absolute position in pixel, because this is a web page and I do not not how wide the browser will be, image can change in the future, text in the button can change in the future, all this things affect absolute size.
If there is another solution to my problem which would prevent the page from jumping up and down it would also be great.

EDIT
Link to one of fiddle experiments:
https://jsfiddle.net/ofb2qdt8/

```
.button {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 30px;
    background: blue;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
}

.spinner {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    background:red;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

This renders second element underneath on screen. Not on different z layer.

Experiment 2:
https://jsfiddle.net/ofb2qdt8/

```
.button {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 30px;
    background: blue;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
}

.spinner {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    height: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    background:red;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

This does not center both elements, and they are pushed to the top of the containing div. The element with less height should be centered.

Comment: You need to show us some code.

Comment: Your code could explain more about your requirement so try to add some fiddle to discus more about your problum

Comment: I have tried may variations and I see little point to post it all, because it would add to the confusion. But I will edit question and add fiddle link to some nonworking things I have tried.

Comment: Because the question is not explained very well at all. The jsFiddle seems completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

Check this working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ofb2qdt8/3/

Add in a few lines of jquery and update your `css`.

Position your loading div according to button div's position, width, height using jquery.

*Click the button to see loading div, and try to play the margin of the button to any pixel.

###JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.c2').each(function () {
    $(this).css({
      'width': $(this).siblings('.c1').outerWidth(),
      'height': $(this).siblings('.c1').outerHeight(),
      'top': $(this).siblings('.c1').offset().top,
      'left': $(this).siblings('.c1').offset().left
    });
  });
  $('.c2').on('click', function () {
    $(this).hide(0);
  });
});
```

###CSS

```
.c1 {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}

.c2 {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rough, ready and untested:

HTML

```
<div>
    <input type='submit' />
    <img src="spinneyIMage.gif" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{ text-align: center; }
div img{ display: none; }
```

jQuery

```
$('submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide().next().show();
});
```

After the Ajax call completes reverse the above jQuery.

Comment: As decribed in my question, this is wrong. This causes the page to flicker, change position of other elemnts on page and what not. This was the first thing I tried. This would only be feasible if button and spinner image would occupy exactly the same height to the pixel exact.

Answer (score -2):

As I haven't been able to find a working solution I have reverted to my first idea which I discarded at first. Albeit with a little twist.

HTML

```
<div class="row>
    <div id="container-button" class="col-xs-12>
        <button id="button" onclick="button_OnClick(e)">submit form via ajax</button>
        <img src="img/spinner.png" sytle="display: none" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function btnContact_OnClick() {
    // show the soinner and hide the button
    showSpinner();
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: "someurl.com/target",
            data: $("#form").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function() { hideSpinner();},
            success: onAjaxSuccess,
            error : onAjaxError
        }); 
}

function hideSpinner() {
    $("#spinner").hide();
    $("#button").show();
    // make container height non-fixed and content adjustable again
    $("#container-button").height('auto');
}


function showSpinner() {
    // THis is the trick !!!
    // Make the container fixed height as it was before displaying spinner, so it does not change with content (spinner is not the same height as button
    $("#container-button").height($("#container-button").height());
    $("#button").hide();
    $("#spinner").show();
}
```

This is not the perfect solution but the best I could make.
Drawbacks:

- it is not clean, you have to use javasript to fix what is css layout
  problem
- it still causes a little flicker
- the height of container while displaying spinner is dependant on button, this may cause clipping if spinner is too big